# Two different android studio but same project, are they generated differently?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

My laptop has dual boot Ubuntu/Windows and my project is in github. Usually I used to code in ubuntu's android studio. But yesterday I pulled my project to windows android studio from github and when I compiled the project while installing on a device it said

Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]

What does this mean?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you deploy an app to a device or the emulator, the APK needs to be signed with a key from a Java keystore.

You typically first encounter this process when you want to upload your app to the Play Store. Before doing so, you must sign your APK with a key that you will use to sign all future release builds. You typically generate this key yourself, and you cannot lose it- without it, you cannot release a new version of your app.

However, debug builds during development must also be signed to deploy to a device. The catch is that by default, debug builds are signed with a debug keystore that is generated when you first set up your development environment. Because of this, the debug keystore is different on every computer, and when you try to install your application from a different computer the device will rightfully complain that the app it has installed doesn't have the same certificate as the new version you are trying to install.

There are two potential solutions for this-

- Simply uninstall the app and try deploying it again.
- Put a keystore (such as one of your debug keystores) in source control, and explicitly use that key to sign your debug builds by [defining a signing configuration in Gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Signing-Configurations).

Note that on windows, your debug keystore is typically located at `C:\Users\[username]\.android\debug.keystore`.

Comment: Thanks!! Learned a lot from your answer. But one more curiosity. If I use same keystore and key alias on different development. Does this generate same key(Release) and won't show this issue?

Comment: Using the same key for debug builds on different development computers will fix this issue. You can (and should) still use a separate key for releases though.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I understood everything.