# Working on same project on different computers forces me to uninstall app

Tags: android, android-studio

Sometimes I work with my laptop. But when I am at home, I work with my PC. I just put the project on Dropbox and continue working on it from a different PC. But every time I run the app from Android Studio, I have to uninstall due to ***different signature*** thing.  It is **debug** version not release so IDE does signing automatically. I am developing an app just for myself, even I am upgrading it, I don't want to lose my info stored previously.

So how can I prevent uninstalling?

Comment: It is debug version not release. IDE does it automatically. No need to downvote.

Comment: I have asked it already and also got the answer.[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882525/two-different-android-studio-but-same-project-are-they-generated-differently)

Comment: Thanks!!. Write your comment as answer so i can select your comment as best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into `Build > Edit Build Type > Module : app > Signing` and create a new one, then select on the `Build Type tab > Signins Config`.

Now you just have to share the keystore on your Dropbox.

Comment: key.jks is in the project folder so copying project will be enough? (I did what u said by the way)

Comment: The best is to not share the idea conf file between computer. Use git, ignore all the /.idea folder and *.iml files. Share your jks on the git and configure both of your PC to use the jks